# Django how can I specify a different authentication method per view

Tags: python, django, authentication, cas

Pretty much what the title says.

I'm using Django 1.11 and I've been asked to set CAS as authentication method to some of views, and keep the rest behind Django model auth or leave them without authentication.

I'm trying to integrate `django_cas_ng` into my project to redirect to a CAS server for authentication, but I can't figure out how to distinguish the auth method among view functions. Django supports multiple auth backends, or even completely customized ones, but I wonder if I can specify a separate auth method by name for each view (for example with a view decorator).

Django allows explicitly specifying different databases and caches, but is there a way (or an app) to enable the same for authentication backends?

Answer (score 1):

Django default auth:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
class AnyView(AnyViewClass):
    ...
```

You can use for aouth-views:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes, authentication_classes
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

    @authentication_classes((BasicAuthentication,))
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
    class AnyView(APIView):
        ...
```

And for any-other auth like oauth2:

```
from oauth2_provider.decorators import protected_resource

@protected_resource()
class AnyView(APIView):
    ...
```

For do not copy-paste you can create two classes with different auth-types and use them as parent-classes for other.

Comment: Is this specific to django-rest-framework? because I'm not using it in my app for anything else. Just regular django view functions.

Comment: @aalizadeh second variant yep, try with first